# Card Matchmaking trouble in Pygames

Tags: python, memory, pygame, matching, playing-cards

I have a code for a memory game in pygame. The problem I am trying to resolve is making the cards flip back down once the user selects two cards that are not matching. If any one could help that would be great. Thanks!

```
 import pygame


 from pygame.locals import*


 # Colours
 black = (  0,  0,  0)
 white = (255,255,255)
 red   = (100,  0,  0)
 green = (  0,153,  0)
 blue  = (  0,  0,255)
 pink  = (255,  0,220)
 img1 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 again = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img2 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img3 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img4 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img5 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img6 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img7 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img8 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img9 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 img10 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 pic1 = pygame.image.load("playing-card-back.jpeg")
 side1 = pygame.image.load("200px-Playing_card_diamond_10.svg_.png")
 side2=pygame.image.load("300px-Poker-sm-21A-5s.png")
 side3 = pygame.image.load("deck-of-cards-clipartace-of-spades-playing-card---free-clip-                art-68ezag1x.png")
 side4 = pygame.image.load("Poker-sm-233-Qd.png")
 side5 = pygame.image.load("jackspades.png")
 background = pygame.image.load("green-suited-poker-table-felt-400x300.jpeg")
 #Screen
 screenWidth = 1000
 screenHeight = 500


 size = (screenWidth,screenHeight)
 screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


 done = False
 one_matched = False
 two_matched = False
 three_matched = False
 four_matched = False
 five_matched = False


 timesPressed = 0

 screen.blit(background,(0,0))

 pygame.display.flip()

 clock = pygame.time.Clock()

 while done == False:


    for event in pygame.event.get():

        screen.blit(img1,(10,25,100,100))
        screen.blit(img2,(10,250,100,100))
        screen.blit(img3,(210,25,100,100))
        screen.blit(img4,(210,250,100,100))
        screen.blit(img5,(410,25,100,100))
        screen.blit(img6,(410,250,100,100))
        screen.blit(img7,(610,250,100,100))
        screen.blit(img8,(610,25,100,100))
        screen.blit(img9,(810,25,100,100))
        screen.blit(img10,(810,250,100,100))


##        pygame.draw.rect(screen,img,[50,10,100,100])
##        pygame.draw.rect(screen,graphic,[50,150,100,100])
##        pygame.draw.rect(screen,graphic,[200,10,100,100])
##        pygame.draw.rect(screen,graphic,[200,150,100,100])
##        pygame.draw.rect(screen,graphic,[350,10,100,100])
##        pygame.draw.rect(screen,graphic,[350,150,100,100])

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            print"User quit"
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            print "User pressed a key"

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

            print "User pressed a key"



        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and timesPressed < 2:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x, y = event.pos
            print pos



        # Check to see if the click is in the range we want
            if ( x in range(10,110)) and (y in range(25,125)):
                img1 = side1
                timesPressed +=1
                if img2 == side2:
                    one_matched = True



            if (x in range (10,110)) and (y in range (250,350)):
                img2 = side2
                timesPressed +=1

            if (x in range (210,310)) and (y in range (25,125)):
                img3 = side3
                timesPressed +=1

            if (x in range (210,310)) and (y in range (250,350)):
                img4 = side5
                timesPressed +=1

            if (x in range (410,510)) and (y in range (25,125)):
                img5 =side2
                timesPressed +=1

            if (x in range (410,510)) and (y in range (250,350)):
                img6 = side1
                timesPressed +=1

            if (x in range (610,710)) and (y in range (250,350)):
                img7 = side5
                timesPressed +=1

            if (x in range (610,710)) and (y in range (25,125)):
                img8=side4
                timesPressed +=1

            if (x in range (810,910)) and (y in range (25,125)):
                img9 = side4
                timesPressed +=1

            if (x in range (810,910)) and (y in range (250,350)):
                img10 = side3
                timesPressed +=1



        points = 0


##        if timesPressed == 2:
##            img1 = again


        print "points", points




        clock.tick(30)
        print timesPressed






##        image(0,0)
        print one_matched
        pygame.display.flip()






if img2 == side3:
    if img9 == side3:
        three_matched = True
        timesPressed = 0
        points += 1
    else:
        three_matched = False

if img3 == side2:
    if img4 == side2:
        two_matched = True
        timesPressed = 0
        points += 1
    else:
        two_matched = False


if img5 == side5:
    if img7 == side5:
        five_matched = True
        timesPressed = 0
        points += 1
    else:
        five_matched = False

if img9 == side4:
    if img9 == side4:
        four_matched = True
        timesPressed = 0
        points += 1
    else:
         four_matched = False

if two_matched == True:
    points += 1

if three_matched == True:
    points += 1

if four_matched == True:
    points += 1

if five_matched == True:
    points += 1

if one_matched == False:
    points == 0

if two_matched == False:
    points == 0

if three_matched == False:
    points == 0

if four_matched == False:
    points == 0

if five_matched == False:
    points == 0


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: We are lazy and do not like reading that much code. You probably won't get a great answer without simplifying the question.

Comment: Why do you load the same image so many times

Answer (score 2):

You load many copies if the same image. Instead load `playing-card-back.jpeg` once, and use it repeatedly.

You are blitting multiple times per one loop, once for every event fired.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    screen.blit(img1,(10,25,100,100))
    screen.blit(img2,(10,250,100,100))
```

Instead, render once per frame:

```
# handle events
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        # ...
# draw
screen.blit(img1,(10,25,100,100))
# ...

# flip
pygame.display.flip()
```

Use `Rect.collide*` to check to see if the click is in the range we want

```
# instead of
if (x in range (10,110)) and (y in range (250,350)):

# use
for card in cards:
    if card.rect.collidepoint(x,y)
        print("You clicked on {}".format(card))
```